# Multipart data upload in android is not working

Tags: android, upload, multipart

I'm trying to upload multipart data in android but my code isn't working. My code is below. My upload information is mostly text fields. So I kept a HashMap so that the key will contain the field name and the value will contain the field value. But my solution isn't working. Please someone focus me on what I'm doing wrong here.

```
public static boolean uploadMultipartData(String urlString, HashMap<String, Object> dataMap){
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    DataOutputStream outStream = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "---------------------------265001916915724";



    if (dataMap != null){
        try {
            StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : dataMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();

                outStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\""
                                + lineEnd);
                outStream.writeBytes(value.toString());
                outStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            }
            outStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens);
            outStream.flush();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "[MalformedURLException while sending data]");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "[IOException while sending data]");
        }
        finally{
            try {                   
                outStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its how it is here I if u make a bit complicated queries u get no replies shut down....I experienced the same here

Comment: I am working on the same problem right now right now...it's my first time.. on just a glance your code seems ok...I will try to get it work..if it works I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

I am able to send a single image. But when I want to send a textfield value along with the image then it creates problem. My post request is as follows-

```
-----------------------------265001916915724
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

IMAGE DATA GOES HERE

-----------------------------265001916915724

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location"

LOCATION GOES HERE

-----------------------------265001916915724--
```